# I want to find the first empty column on Google sheet and paste data in it, then do the same thing over and over again

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have multiple sheets, and I want to paste a column of data from a sheet where it get overwritten to a sheet where I can see all the columns next to each other, like an historic.

The problem is that my script paste the data in the same column each time.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
function GraphData() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange("Sheet1!B2:B209");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastColumn()+1,+2);

  source.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear ();

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I want to paste a column of data from a sheet where it get overwritten to a sheet where I can see all the columns next to each other, like an historic.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I have two sheets. Sheet1 contain a lot of different data from an external source, that is automatically updated regularly. One column on that sheet interest me, and I want to keep an history from it. For that, I created Sheet2, where I want to paste that column automatically, every few hours. I wanted to make a script that look for the last column with something in it, and then write in the next one to the right.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your question from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: I want this script to find what column is empty. getLastColumn is not working like I want. I can also speak French if you understand it better.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

The order of the parameters matters! On the method [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)), the first parameter refers to the row index, and the second to the column index. You have it backwards, so the range is always getting copied to column B.

#### Solution:

Change the order of the parameters:

```
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(2, destSheet.getLastColumn() + 1);
```

#### Reference:

- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer))